# How do I cast a bool to a BOOL?

Tags: c++, winapi, casting, boolean

Am I safe in casting a C++ bool to a Windows API BOOL via this construct

```
bool mybool = true;
BOOL apiboolean = mybool ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

I'd assume this is a yes because I don't see any obvious problems but I wanted to take a moment to ask only because this may be more subtle than it appears.

*Thanks to Dima for (gently) pointing out my carelessness in the way I'd originally phrased the question.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean

```
bool b;
...
BOOL apiboolean = b ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

If so, then yes, this will work.

Comment: Duh.  Sorry--you're right of course.  Thanks. I'll fix up my question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that will work, but

```
bool b;
...
BOOL apiboolean = (BOOL) b;
```

should work just as well, as does the reverse:

```
bool bb = (bool) apiboolean;
```

Comment: In that case, you should use static_cast<BOOL>(b).

Comment: really you should just let it implicitly cast for you. The compiler knows how to cast between int's and bool's, and BOOL is usually a typedef for some int type.

Comment: Greg, bool to int would probably work, but Visual Studio will give you a warning if you try to cast int to bool.

Comment: Hi guys, yes, I'd considered all those ways of casting--I was only asking, as I said, because I thought there might be some subtle problem that I was missing.  I think I prefer Dima's approach because what I'm doing is just more obvious (for the sake of anyone maintaining this code).

Comment: I use !! for int -> bool. Avoids the warning and less typing than static_cast. Course it looks a little silly.

Comment: @Logan: well, I object to using ! on an int (on principle).  Also, while it's probably optimized to something sensible, the "straight" (non-optimized) translation of that is wicked.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2005 will simply accept:

```
bool b = true;
BOOL apiboolean = b;
```

*no casting required*.

Note that the other way round BOOL->bool does not simply work like this.